# Oracle-Apex link shows different value

Tags: oracle-apex

Column Id (varchar2) shows wrong number.
I checked, everything looks good as for the other columns.

When I click on link which is on ID column

As you can see column Id is 95 for id 1. When I click on id 1:

Id is different number, and for all rows is 9590644622004212.

Comment: Did you try scaping the values with \ITEM\

Comment: How can I do it?

Comment: what is the source for Company Id page item in the form ? Could it be that it is something else than "database column" and that the value is cached which explains why you always see it. Check the attributes of the page item and compare them to the other page items in the form

Comment: The source is a database column as for all items.

Answer (score 1):

In this case if something interfers with your text such as comma (,) or a symbol you can escape it as the image below.

[image]

Comment: wait... are you passing all the values in the link ? Please provide more information in the question. Normally, in a link from a report to a form, you only pass the primary key of the record to the form and the row fetch process will populate all the values. If you're doing it differently... it probably helps is you provide as much information as possible. "I checked and it looks good"... is not something that gives any value. What are the properties of the link ? If you turn on debug and then investigate it, what do you see ?

Comment: did you do as I suggested ? turn on debug and investigate the output. What did that tell you ?

Comment: I didn't add load process, and I removed all items from link except id :)